# Android error while upload to market: The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous one

Tags: android, google-play, code-signing, apk

I am trying to upload the new apk of the application into the market. Unfortunately I'm missing the certificate generated at the time of the first upload. Now I am getting the error

> The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous
>   one.

I know that it can not be recovered so I unpublished my apk from the market and uploaded the new one but still I am getting the same error. What could be the reason of this error, I have unpublished the apk from the market.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must change the Java package name of your new application.

Two different apps (with two different signing keys) cannot share the same package name.